# How to remove duplicate user_id from a query result?

Tags: mysql, database, inner-join, create-view

The problem is I am trying to use Create View for a query but I keep getting an error which means
That I have a duplicate row

My two table structure and relation

[image]

My query

```
SELECT * FROM user_profile as A
INNER JOIN user_personal_info as B 
on A.user_id=B.user_id
```

Results includes two user_id rows and I need B.user_id to be removed to be able to use it like that

```
CREATE View Studentinfo as
SELECT * FROM user_profile as A
INNER JOIN user_personal_info as B 
on A.user_id=B.user_id
```

mysql error #1060 - Duplicate column name 'user_id'

note: I don't want to name each row by its name and exclude B.user_id as I might add more rows and
by that the query would be very long.

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) An ERD is an image of DDL. Debug questions require a [mre]. [ask] [Help]

Comment: This is a faq. Please before considering posting: Pin down code issues via [mre]. Read the manual/reference & google any error message & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. Reflect research in posts. SO/SE search is poor & literal & unusual, read the help. Google re googling/searching, including Q&A at [meta] & [meta.se]. [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [ask] [Help]

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using the `USING` clause instead of `ON`:

```
CREATE VIEW Studentinfo AS
SELECT * 
FROM user_profile AS A INNER JOIN user_personal_info AS B 
USING(user_id);
```

This way the column `user_id` is returned only once.

Note that if you add more columns to the tables (as you say that you intent to) you should take special care so that there is no common column name.